# escaping in crontab

Tags: cron

The following is working as expected at command prompt. But it does not work from cron.

```
# echo "test abc xyz" | grep "test1 \| pqr"

# echo "test abc xyz" | grep "test \| pqr"
test abc xyz
```

When I use this statement in the cron, I need to escape certain characters. But I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to just package that command line into a shell script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing any issue when I am trying to put it in cron. Are you trying to do the same like following:

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ crontab -l
MAILTO=suku@xxxxxx.com
* * * * * /bin/echo "test abc xyz" | grep "test \| pqr" >> stack
* * * * * /bin/echo "test abc xyz" | grep "test1 \| pqr" >> stack_with_1

[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ ls -l stack*
-rw-r--r-- 1 sgeorge eng 13 Jan 11 02:45 stack
-rw-r--r-- 1 sgeorge eng  0 Jan 11 02:45 stack_with_1

[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ cat stack_with_1 
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ cat stack
test abc xyz
```

Comment: In my case it works only if there is no space. for e.g. "test1\|pqr". But you are correct, there is no need of escaping in this case.